# Pyhanko positioning an image

Tags: pdf, pyhanko

I am trying to use pyhanko to add an image (not a signature object) to a PDF. I got to a point that I can add the image, set it's size, but I cannot find how to set it's position. This is the peice of code I wrote:

```
with (open(f'{this_dir}/report-signed1.pdf', 'rb') as rf,
    open(f'{this_dir}/report-signed4.pdf', 'wb') as wf):

    w = IncrementalPdfFileWriter(rf)
    box = layout.BoxConstraints(100, 190)
    img = images.PdfImage(f'{this_dir}/sign.png', box=box, writer=w)
    img.add_to_page(w, page_ix=0)

.
.
.
```

How can I take the image I created it, and set it to any place other than the lower left corner?
Thanks

Comment: I am trying to apply the stamp programmaticlly, howevery, I cannot find where the 50 and 100 should be.